# SQL: Looping over query result

Tags: sql, postgresql, heidisql

*Regarding company tree in PostgreSQL*

I am using the following to get the subsidiaries of the company with id = 11.

```
SELECT * FROM "OwnershipTable" 
WHERE "Parent_ID" = 11;
```

giving me the following output

| Company_ID | Company_Name | Parent_ID | Parent_Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | Holdco 1 | 11 | Topco |
| 112 | Holdco 2 | 11 | Topco |
| 113 | Holdco 3 | 11 | Topco |
| 114 | Holdco 4 | 11 | Topco |

However, I would like to investigate if any of the Holdco-companies has any subsidiaries. My question is therefore: **Is it possible insert the column "Company_ID" as "Parent_ID" in the query using some sort of loop?**

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  This is called a recursive CTE:

```
with recursive cte as (
      select company_id as parent_company_id, company_id as child_id
      from OwnershipTable ot
      where parent_id = 11
      union all
      select cte.parent_company_id, ot.company_id
      from cte join
           OwnershipTable ot
           on ot.parent_id = cte.child_id
     )
select *
from cte;
```

If you want additional information about the companies, you can `join` it in or include it in the recursive CTE definitions.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. However, it is possible for the "children" to have children and so on. To your knowledge is it possible to use a recursive CTE n-times until there is no "children" left?

Comment: @FrederikGrut . . . That is what this query does.  That is why it is using a recursive CTE.  Perhaps you intended the comment on the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
  SELECT * FROM "OwnershipTable" ot
    WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM "OwnershipTable" where Parent_ID = ot.Company_ID)
```